# Is there an alternative to using DATALINES that works within a macro to put text into a dataset in SAS EG?

Tags: sas, sas-macro

Objective: I'm trying to print out a comment that users can see on the Results tab in SAS EG after running an existing macro.

Issue/Question: The problem I'm running into is that DATALINES doesn't work within a macro.

I read that as an alternative, I can save my DATALINES in a text file and read in that file, which would work within macro code. Is there any other way to accomplish the objective or, if not could someone offer some sample code on how the alternative mentioned above would look like?

Existing data set and DATALINES code:

```
DATA prnt_msg;
INPUT COMMENT $150.;
DATALINES;
Zero records in output file after processing load file and ACR error log file - as a result no cocsavings file was produced.
Please ensure that you are using the correct load file and ACR error log file combination, otherwise no cocsavings file is needed.
;
RUN;

PROC PRINT DATA=work.prnt_msg NOOBS ;
 TITLE "NOTE";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a message to user that I would expect to see in the SAS log, rather than the output window.  Maybe use the PUTLOG statement as an alternative, e.g.

```
data _null_;
putlog "WARNING: Zero records in output file after processing load file and ACR error log file - as a result no cocsavings file was produced. Please ensure that you are using the correct load file and ACR error log file combination, otherwise no cocsavings file is needed." ;
run ;
```

But if you really want COMMENT in a dataset, you could just hardcode it:

```
DATA prnt_msg;
  length COMMENT $150;
  Comment="Zero records in output file after processing load file and ACR error log file - as a result no cocsavings file was produced.";
  output;
  Comment="Please ensure that you are using the correct load file and ACR error log file combination, otherwise no cocsavings file is needed.";
  output;
run ;
```

Comment: Thanks Quentin. Exactly what I needed. Agreed, I tried telling the stakeholder exactly what you stated about the message already being in the log; but as it happens sometimes they confuse a "need to have" with a "would like to have". Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to use `Proc SQL` to `insert` rows.

Note that there is no comma between the `values` clauses.

```
proc sql;
  create table print_msg (comment char(150)) ;

  insert into print_msg
  values ('Zero records in output fil...')
  values ('Please ensure that you are...')
  ;
```